# Split multiple, multiline messages into matches

Tags: regex

I am trying to split multiple messages (like in a chat log), which would be separated by the username and date. The issue is that using the g modifier makes regex match *everything* until the last part. It is somewhat difficult to to explain, so here's a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lM1kB0/1) that would explain it better.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What Language are you using?

Comment: It will be in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your regex `lazy` using `?`

```
(.*?), (\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+:\d+])\n([\s\S]*?)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM1kB0/3)**

Moreover, there is no need of last part when using `g` modifier. This will suffice

```
(.*?), (\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+:\d+])
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM1kB0/4)**

If you want to capture the message, then you can use

```
 (.*?), (\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+:\d+])\n([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:(?:.*?), (?:\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+:\d+]))|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM1kB0/6)**

Comment: Almost what I need, it must also capture the message itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.